# docker unable to navigate to a web site using https

Tags: windows, docker

I have the following trivial docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

WORKDIR /azp

COPY test.ps1 .

CMD powershell .\test.ps1
```

Where test.ps1 is:

```
C:\test> cat .\test.ps1
curl https://cnn.com -UseBasicParsing
```

The script can run just fine on my machine, but not in a docker container:

```
C:\test> docker build -t test:latest .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  75.26kB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> 782a75e44953
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /azp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b43270631602
Step 3/4 : COPY test.ps1 .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 10cfc66cff37
Step 4/4 : CMD powershell .\test.ps1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 187be18c5495
Successfully built 187be18c5495
Successfully tagged test:latest
C:\test> docker run test
curl : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
At C:\azp\test.ps1:1 char:1
+ curl https://cnn.com -UseBasicParsing
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt
   pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Note that replacing `https://cnn.com` (**https**) with `http://google.com` (**http**) works, so this is clearly something about the https.

What am I missing?

**P.S.**

I am using Windows 10 with the most recent docker switched to use windows containers.

Comment: Search this? `Could not establish trust
relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel` Why not use https on Google as well?

Comment: Google or cnn - same result. Does not matter. I searched, but did not find the answer. The time in the container matches the expected time. The certificate - what certificate? If you know the answer - please post it and I will be happy to check it and credit you, if it works.

Comment: I don't know PowerShell. But I would assume openssl is not available in the container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I managed to make it work for **https://google.com** by following these steps:

1. Navigate to **https://google.com** and check what is the root certificate. It is a certificate with thumbprint `75E0ABB6138512271C04F85FDDDE38E4B7242EFE`
2. Export the aforementioned certificate as well as the ZScaler root certificate (`D72F47D87420E3F0F9BDCAC6F03A566743C481B9`) to a special directory that will be included in the image under `C:\containers`.
3. Modify the test.ps1 script - see below.
4. Modify the Dockerfile script - see below.

**test.ps1**

```
Get-ChildItem /certificates | ForEach-Object {
    $null = Import-Certificate -FilePath $_.FullName -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
}

$res = Invoke-WebRequest https://google.com -UseBasicParsing
$res.StatusDescription
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
COPY certificates certificates
WORKDIR /azp
COPY test.ps1 .
CMD powershell .\test.ps1
```

So, on the host machine I run the following commands:

```
C:\test> $certs = dir Cert:\LocalMachine\Root |? { $_.Thumbprint -eq '75E0ABB6138512271C04F85FDDDE38E4B7242EFE' -or $_.Thumbprint -eq 'D72F47D87420E3F0F9BDCAC6F03A566743C481B9' }
C:\test> $certs


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\Root

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
D72F47D87420E3F0F9BDCAC6F03A566743C481B9  E=support@zscaler.com, CN=Zscaler Root CA, OU=Zscaler Inc., O=Zscaler Inc., L=San Jose, S=California, C=US
75E0ABB6138512271C04F85FDDDE38E4B7242EFE  CN=GlobalSign, O=GlobalSign, OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2


C:\test> $certs |% { Export-Certificate -FilePath "c:\test\certificates\$($_.Thumbprint).cer" -Cert $_ }


    Directory: C:\test\certificates


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         1/5/2020   8:40 PM           1239 D72F47D87420E3F0F9BDCAC6F03A566743C481B9.cer
-a----         1/5/2020   8:40 PM            958 75E0ABB6138512271C04F85FDDDE38E4B7242EFE.cer


C:\test> docker run test
OK
C:\test>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your container is not able to verify TLS server certificate. Probably CA certificates (maybe they have different technical term in the Windows) are missing in the container.

You can:

- `-SkipCertificateCheck` (available from PowerShell V6.0+), so TLS cert verification will be skipped - good choice for development, but it will sacrifice security partially
- "mount Windows hosts certificate store in container" - [Docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/mount-windows-hosts-certificate-store-in-containers/76388)

Comment: Well the docker forum does not provide an answer :-(. Amazing, does anyone at all use windows containers?

Comment: @mark probably https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=windowscontainers is better, more specific forum for this problem